# List comprehension or map() or for loop for accessing previous row to manipulate array

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy, list-comprehension

Say I have an array(numpy array) `A = [[1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]` and I want to manipulate the zero rows into `[2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2]` so the final array is `A = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2]]`

I am able to do this with a for loop which looks like:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0]])
for i in xrange(1,3):
    a[i]=np.concatenate([a[i-1][1:], a[i-1][:1]], axis=1)
```

Go get the previous row, concatenate [1:] and [:1], **assign** the result as the next row.

I have a number of these loops and I wonder if I can get rid of for loops so I get some more speed (maybe?). Is there a way I can do this using list comprehension or map? My A array doesn't have to be nxn with zero rows except for the first, it can be just `A = [1, 2, 3, ..., n]` if there's a way I can **create** an array of nx3 using A as a starter and keep taking the previous row and concatenating `[m:]` and `[:m]` of it. (arbitrary m)

Or yes, maybe for loop is the only/correct way of doing such operation. I would like to know if it is.

Comment: I've deleted my answer because I think your recent edit changes the original scope significantly and goes beyond what can be achieved easily by adjusting an array's strides. An iterative approach would be the only reasonable way (albeit at the cost of speed).

Comment: I was just about to ask you how I could use it for [m:] instead of [1:] because the method you suggested looked like a good speed upgrade for my script. My only concern with this problem is speed and it is a matter of seconds really. My current script runs in 10 seconds, knowing that there are faster methods than nested for loops, I thought maybe I could get it to run faster. But for this particular problem the for loop I use, or numpy.roll that Daniel suggested or zip() that @Kasra suggested appear to be the suitable applications which I think won't affect my script's speed that much.

Comment: Strides are a very quick way of doing some of the manipulation, but they don't handle the `[:m]` slicing part well. If it's an option, you could always look to use Cython to speed up iterative approaches.

Comment: I've edited my answer to a fully-vectorized solution which can be over an order of magnitude faster depending on the size of the original array. See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A for-loop is the easiest way, list comprehension or map would not gain much speed. But you can use `roll` instead of concatenation:

```
a = numpy.array([1, 2, 3])
a = numpy.vstack([numpy.roll(a, -i) for i in xrange(3)])
```

Comment: This would make my code shorter and look prettier, syntax is easy too. But again, the actual thing I wanna do is get faster with my script. Isn't it a list comprehension in the parentheses of .vstack? I think this would run faster than for loop but I need to test and see what happens. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a way using python `zip` built-in function.You can concatenate your array with itself then all you need is picking every 3 followed elements!

```
>>> A=np.arange(1,4)
>>> B=np.concatenate((A,A))
>>> B
array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])
>>> np.array(zip(B,B[1:],B[2:])[:-1])
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 1],
       [3, 1, 2]])
```

You can use this recipe for longer arrays :

```
>>> A=np.arange(1,6)
>>> B=np.concatenate((A,A))
>>> np.array(zip(B,B[1:],B[2:])[:-1])
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [4, 5, 1],
       [5, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4]])
>>>
```

Comment: This is useful too. I was able to adapt this solution to my problem. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution which avoids loops in Python. 
You can get the desired output by creating an array of indices which you can use to index into you're original array:

```
In [40]:

    a = np.arange(1, 4)
    i = np.arange(len(a))
    indexer = i - np.atleast_2d(i).T 
    a[indexer]

Out[40]:
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [3, 1, 2],
       [2, 3, 1]])
```

This will work for any `a`. The `indexer` array is the size of the desired output and is created using broadcasting. In this case it looks like

```
array([[ 0,  1, 2], 
       [-1,  0, 1], 
       [-2, -1, 0]])
```

Here are some time comparisons with the looping methods which shows it's considerably faster:

```
In [69]:

%%timeit 
a = np.arange(1, 11)
i = np.arange(0, len(a), step_size)
indexer = i - np.atleast_2d(i).T 
a[indexer]
10000 loops, best of 3: 14.7 µs per loop

In [70]:

%%timeit
a = numpy.arange(1, 11)
a = numpy.vstack([numpy.roll(a, -i) for i in xrange(len(a))])
10000 loops, best of 3: 143 µs per loop

In [71]:

%%timeit 
a = np.arange(1, 101)
i = np.arange(0, len(a), step_size)
indexer = i - np.atleast_2d(i).T 
a[indexer]
10000 loops, best of 3: 80 µs per loop

In [72]:

%%timeit
a = numpy.arange(1, 101)
a = numpy.vstack([numpy.roll(a, -i) for i in xrange(len(a))])
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.44 ms per loop
```

This also has the advantage that you can re-use `indexer` to manipulate other arrays of the same length in the same way. If you really wanted you could also write it to disk. 
For an arbitrary step size `m` you can do the following:

```
In [61]:

m = 2
a = np.arange(1, 4)
i = np.arange(len(a))
indexer = (i - m * np.atleast_2d(i).T) % len(a)
a[indexer]

Out[61]:
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 1],
       [3, 1, 2]])
```